# Dummy Partition Keys in Cassandra and Range Queries

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and of all my research I'm finding it hard to come up with a decent solution. My end goal is to be able to do a range query of my data, however I don't have a good partition key for the type of query I want to make.

Imagine I have users, comments and timestamp they were created and I want to a search by a range like all comments before a particular date. I know that a range query for a clustering key is easy to do however I can't have a partition key be users as they will have a lot of comments and it will lead to several problems as unbounded and skewed partitions.

So I'm finding it really hard to find a partition key that could fit. One pseudo solution I found is dummy columns. If I can have :

```
((users,dummy),comments,timestamp)
```

as my primary key that would help me but that leads to unbounded partitions as well. Now my question is if there isn't a better way to do this somehow is it possible to calculate when my partition is reaching the maximum desirable size which I read is 100mb and change the dummy?

Something like sharding if I understand the concept correctly: I have 
`((users,shard1)...)` and in my logic when I notice shard 1 is reaching the maximum desired capacity I start placing values into the next shard (shard2) and so on. Then I have a table like (users,shards) that gives me the amount of shards each user has.

Is this possible? I've met this problem in Cassandra and I'm searching for the best plausible solution to it or if there really isn't any.

Comment: Are you trying to find all comments for a particular user within a timestamp range, or all comments for all users in a timestamp range? If the first, one option could be to include a column that has a date without a time (e.g. yyyymmdd). The PK could look like: ((users, dateWithoutTime), timestamp, comments). You would fire separate queries against the table for each date within the range (You could also use an IN clause, but that is not as efficient). You could even use the timestamp ranges as well to narrow down more. If you want all comments for all users, you have bigger issues.

Comment: I want all comments for all users unfortunately.

Comment: Well then maybe your PK could be: (dateWithoutTime, timestamp, users, comments). In that case, you would fire a query for each date including your timestamp as well if you want hours/minutes/seconds to get involved. Not the greatest, but it would limit partitions so they do not grow unbounded and you can also use the range of the timestamp. How many days are you talking about in the range - is it days', weeks', months' worth of data you're reviewing? Obviously it's painful to have separate queries for each day, but it is the most efficient (v.s. a single IN clause).

Comment: Months, almost a year in some cases